# Non-clustered index with all columns for "select * from"?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, nonclustered-index

I have a simple `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DataDate = '18-AUG-2013'` query on a table that contains 340 columns and 3.4M rows.

Running estimated Execution plan in SSMS (Ctrl-L) suggests I create a non-clustered index on the DataDate and include every other column?

Is that a sensible thing to do (in general terms)?
Seems to me that this would vastly increase the indexing space and the indexing time on inserts etc. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely don't do that. The missing index hints can be very useful but the [recommendations can be dumb](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204043251/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bartd/archive/2007/07/19/are-you-using-sql-s-missing-index-dmvs.aspx), occasionally outright ridiculous. Creating a copy of the entire table for the benefit of this query fits the later.

If your most common queries use a predicate on `DataDate` then it may be appropriate to change your tables clustered index to this. Only you can make that call based on your understanding of the workload.

`SELECT *` on a 340 column table smells suspicious. Do you really need all of those columns, every time?

Comment: `SELECT * ` is actually to archive data older than a certain date - which is to be followed by a `delete from` - hence NOT wanting to add that index!

Comment: @BlueChippy - What edition of SQL Server are you on? If Enterprise have you considered partitioning to quickly switch  out archived data? In any event you can potentially combine the `DELETE` and the `INSERT` with the `OUTPUT INTO` clause to avoid the need for an `INSERT ... SELECT` followed by a `DELETE`.

Comment: On Standard, sadly (due to cost of Enterprise) - otherwise I'd be partitioning.

Comment: Could you please clarify why it's always a bad idea? What would be the drawbacks (other than obvious writes slowing down)? What are the alternatives if, for example, I actually need all of these columns for queries A and B, both of which needs different ORDER BY columns?